# Prolog- Returning elements from facts

Tags: prolog, return, element, fact

i encounter a problem with facts. Let's say i got 3 facts and `check(X)` question.

```
fact(a,b).
fact(b,c).
fact(a,d).

check(X):-
//some calculation with fact()
```

How to make above question to return list of elements for given `X` from all facts?
For instance: `check(a)` would give result `b` and `d`. So i can use this const later.
`check(b)` would return `c`. I would be grateful for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra argument for the list. So you cannot call it `check/1` having a single argument, but — let's say — `related_to/2`.

```
related_to(X, Ys) :-
   setof(Y, fact(X, Y), Ys).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- related_to(a, Xs).
   Xs = [b, d].
?- related_to(b, Xs).
   Xs = [c].
?- related_to(d, Xs).
   false.
?- related_to(X, Xs).
   X = a, Xs = [b,d]
;  X = b, Xs = [c].
```

Note that the relation will fail for inexistent nodes like `d` above. On the other hand, you can even ask the **most general goal** getting all possible answers at once.

Also note that this relation is not monotone: If you add further facts, previously obtained results no longer hold. Like by adding `fact(a,f)` the goal `related_to(a, [b,d])` no longer holds. Instead `related_to(a,[b,d,f])` now holds.